# Software that can synchronize links as "bookmarks"?

Tags: linux, web-browser, bookmark, synchronization

AFAIK browser bookmarks are just regular http links. Now I use [Google Bookmarks](https://www.google.com/bookmarks/) to store my links. It used to be possible to access the bookmarks from Google Chrome so that if I switch computers or reinstall, then I can keep my bookmarks from being logged in with my Google or Chrome account.

Now it seems that the option is discontinued in Google Chrome to use Google Bookmarks directly. There was a workaround to install a button "add to Google Bookmarks" but it was third-party and not ideal because it ran a third-party script and could have been easier. I also can't find that add-on anymore.

Can you recommend a good way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Either Firefox or Chrome will do, and I'm also interested in alternatives to Google Bookmarks if there are any, maybe Mozilla has some service. I just want this one thing and do it well. There are services like del.icio.us that does many unnecessary things with bookmarks, now all I would like is synchronize my bookmarks between browsers.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your wish correctly. If it is have all bookmarks on all your browsers on all your computers you use I recommend [Xmarks](https://www.xmarks.com/). If you just use Chrome on all computers synchronization is already built-in.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome if you go to chrome://bookmarks/ you will be in the bookmark manager if you click on Organise you will get the option to export your bookmarks to a HTML file, *Tested with Chrome 55.0.2883.87 on Windows 10*.
[image]

In Firefox if you press Ctrl+Shift+B you will get the bookmarks window and under "Import and Backup" you will again have options to export to and import from html files, *Tested with Firefox 50.1.0 on Windows 10*.

[image]

There is also an option to import from a html file from Google Bookmarks but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent import.

*Needless to say IE11 and Edge have both made this simple operation a minefield.*

Comment: No need to worry and do this manually, just use [Xmarks](https://www.xmarks.com/). Then also Internet Explorer and Safari work.

Answer (score 1):

**Google Chrome** offers a very good method to synchronize bookmarks (btw also extensions):

When you sign in to Chrome on all your devices, they'll all show the same info:

Bookmarks
History and open tabs
Passwords
Autofill info and credit cards
Settings and preferences

You get more information on [Google Chrome Account](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/165139?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en-GB)

Answer (score 1):

Found this one recently, it is working delightfully for me between Microsoft Edge, Google Chrome, Vivaldi, and Firefox, Linux and Windows:

https://xbrowsersync.org

Sorry, should have put this in originally: I have zero affiliation with this product.

Comment: Hi Jeb.  The system has flagged your answers because you just left 3 identical answers all recommending the same product.  Please disclose to our community if you happen to have any affiliation with this product.  Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely zero affiliation whatsoever.  I just saw three almost identical questions, and I've been struggling with that very issue for quite a few years now.